# Remove Identical Words from a string array

Tags: c#

The goal is to remove a certain prefix word from a string in string array example: `["Market1", "Market2", "Market3"]`.  The prefix word `Market` is dominant in string array, so we have to remove Market from string array so the result should be `["1", "2", "3"]`.  Please take note that the `Market` prefix word in string could be anything.

Comment: Is it always constant prefix + number?

Comment: No it's, not, sometimes words, sometimes integers... so typically all is consist with strings

Comment: it could be ```["MarketIndia", "MarketPhilippines", "MarketSingapore"]``` something like that..

Comment: Is it always begin of string? Is this constant part is known before?

Comment: @Leszek Mazur Absolutely right...

Comment: StackOverflow is _not_ a free "do-my-homework" service. Here is [no attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and [no code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the first character that is not identical among all strings and select a substring starting at that position to remove the prefix.

```
string[] words = new string[] { "Market1", "Market2", "Market3" };
int i = 0;
while (words.All(word => word.Length > i && word[i] == words[0][i])) ++i;
var wordsWithoutPrefixes = words.Select(word => word.Substring(i)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ:

```cs
string[] myArray = ["Market1", "Market2", "Market3"];

string prefix = myArray[0];
foreach (var s in myArray)
{
  while (!s.StartsWith(prefix))
    prefix = prefix.Substring(0, prefix.Length - 1);
}

string[] result = myArray
  .Select(s => s.Substring(prefix.Length))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: My bad, What if let's say that prefix is unknown, for example ```["ItemNameBluetooth", "ItemNameLED", "ItemNameSurroundSound"]``` which is `ItemName` is the dominant word in string array... so the prefix could be anything as long as it is present in the string in string array...

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each item in the array and for each item chop off the beginning the start matches.

```
var commonPrefix = "Market";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length, i++) {
    if(arr[i].IndexOf(commonPrefix) == 0) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].Substring(commonPrefix.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `StartsWith` instead `indexOf(...) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Make a delimited string and then replace all the `Market` with an empty string and then split the string to an array.

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "Market1", "Market2", "Market3" };
string[] result = string.Join(".", arr).Replace("Market", "").Split('.');
```

Comment: aka, how to give your GC grief.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array of string and replace the substring containing prefix with an empty substring.

```
   string[] s=new string[]{"Market1","Market2","Market3"};
     string prefix="Market";
        foreach(var x in s)
        {
            if(x.Contains(prefix))
            {
                    x=x.Replace(prefix,"");
        
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try to add some context to your answer, code only answers are considered low-quality.